# Como eu faço para abrir uma ViewController através do Local Notification?

Tags: ios, swift, view, local-notification

Tenho uma aplicação que envia notificações ao usuário de tempos em tempos, porém como faço para abrir uma View sem ser a View principal, quando o usuário clica na notificação?

Exemplo, conversas do Whatsapp, notificações do Messenger, ou seja abrem telas específicas através da notificação.

Estou usando a Notificação local e não a Notificação Remota(Push).

Gostaria de um exemplo simples e que não precise necessariamente de conexão com a internet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No **iOS** você não abre uma *view* diretamente (como pode ser feito no *Android*) e sim é aberta a aplicação para então abrir a tela que você deseja. Isso tudo é feito no seu **AppDelegate**, mais ou menos assim:

No `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`, que é por onde o ciclo de vida do seu aplicativo se inicia assim que for aberto ao pressionar a notificação, você terá isso:

```
if let options: NSDictionary = launchOptions {
    var localNotification = options.objectForKey(UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey) as? NSDictionary

    if localNotification != nil {
        handleLocalNotification(application, userInfo: localNotification!)
    }
}
```

Isso indica que seu aplicativo está sendo aberto através da notificação e foi encerrado antes, por isso vai receber essa chave que existe no `launchOptions`.

O método `handleLocalNotification` é o que vai executar as funções que você deseja com as informações da notificação:

```
func handleLocalNotification(application: UIApplication, userInfo: NSDictionary?) {
    window?.rootViewController = viewController
}
```

Aqui, você tem a variável `userInfo` com informações da sua notificação (caso exista algo) e `viewController` é a sua *view*, que a inicialização dela vai depender de como você está fazendo o seu projeto, é algo similar ao que você já deve ter implementado.

E a implementação do *delegate* `didReceiveLocalNotification`, caso não tenha sido encerrado e que submete para o mesmo método que criamos acima:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveLocalNotification notification: UILocalNotification) {
    handleLocalNotification(application, userInfo: notification.userInfo)
}
```

Comment: Isso é feito tudo dentro do AppDelegate certo?

Comment: Isso, o primeiro trecho dentro do método `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` e o segundo é o eu criei, só para ficar separado, mas você pode colocar tudo lá naquela condição de dentro.

Comment: Eu testei e não abriu a View... O que posso estar fazendo de errado? Dentro do handleLocalNotification() eu chamei um println() pra ver se estava chamando o método realmente, mas pelo visto não.

Comment: Eu coloquei um println dentro do handle para ver se estava chamando mas pelo visto não...

Comment: Ops, desculpe, esqueci a implementação do *delegate* `didReceiveLocalNotification`. Existe a situação de quando o aplicativo é aberta após ele ser encerrado (para quando entra pelo `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`) e quando é aberto sem que ele tenha sido encerrado. Quando digo encerrado, é quando o usuário pressiona duas vezes o botão *home* e finaliza o aplicativo, ou caso o seu aplicativo não permita rodar em *background*.

Comment: Ah sim! Creio que agora funcione, porém o que preciso implementar dentro do didReceiveLocalNotification?

Comment: Coloquei na edição da minha resposta. Vai apenas submeter ao método que já criamos lá em cima. Também alterei o parâmetro `userInfo` para opcional, já que pode ser que você não queria passar nada na notificação, apenas abrir uma tela.

Comment: Muito obrigado! Agora funcionou!